# How can i get gallery images from gallery Shortcode in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, image-gallery

I have wordpress page with content and image gallery. when i print_r my content,it shows like below

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [ID] => 4558
    [post_author] => 1
    [post_date] => 2011-09-22 05:34:44
    [post_date_gmt] => 2011-09-22 05:34:44
    [post_content] => 

Nayer has pursued her passion for art since childhood. 
She believes that art should have a positive influence in the world and on our life experiences. 
She studied in Persia at Tehran University and at California State University, Los Angeles.



    [gallery link="file" columns="2"]

        [post_title] => About the Water Artist
        [post_excerpt] => 
        [post_status] => publish
        [comment_status] => open
        [ping_status] => open
        [post_password] => 
        [post_name] => about-the-water-artist
        [to_ping] => 
        [pinged] => 
        [post_modified] => 2011-11-22 04:59:58
        [post_modified_gmt] => 2011-11-22 04:59:58
        [post_content_filtered] => 
        [post_parent] => 0
        [guid] => http://nagu.wordpress.net/?page_id=4558
        [menu_order] => 0
        [post_type] => page
        [post_mime_type] => 
        [comment_count] => 0
        [ancestors] => Array
            (
            )

        [filter] => raw
    )
```

from the above response in [post_content] i found gallery shortcode [gallery link="file" columns="2"]. the images are not shown.

Is there any possibility to extract the images url alone using that shortcode from post content?.

Comment: I too am interested in finding this out

Comment: @Jordan Rynard  i posted answer below. it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use below code for extract images from gallery shortcode, It's working.

```
<?php   
global $post;
global $wp_query;
    $currentPageCatId = get_cat_ID( "pagename" );
        $NewsCatPostsArray = query_posts( 'cat='.$currentPageCatId);

         $current_news_postId = $NewsCatPostsArray[$i]->ID;
                                        $current_news_postUrl = get_permalink($current_news_postId);
                                        $query_images_args = array('post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' =>'image', 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'posts_per_page' => -1,'post_parent' => $current_news_postId);

                                        $query_images = new WP_Query($query_images_args);
                                        $images = array();
                                        foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image) {
                                            $images[]= $image->guid;
                                        }
?>
```